# Scala Play Framework, combine Json validation constrains?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I wondering how it is possible to add number of validation constrains to one field. Now I use validation like this:

```
(JsPath \ "title").readNullable[String](minLength[String](2))
```

How to add maxLengthString to this field?
I've tried it like this:

```
(JsPath \ "title").readNullable[String](minLength[String](2))(maxLength[String](250))
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: There are examples in the documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators andKeep/keepAnd is probably what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for-

```
(JsPath \ "title").readNullable[String](minLength[String](2) keepAnd mixLength[String](250))
```